# Can't get flash on top of HTML

Tags: html, css, flash, z-index, wmode

I'm using SWFObject to embed a swf and it ends up covering some HTML components on the page. However the HTML is bleeding through on top of the flash movie.

I've played with wmode settings and z-index's, absolute vs relative positioning and nothing seems to work in firefox / safari. Chrome is working exactly as I would expect with wmode=window (the flash is always on top of HTML).

Any ideas how I can tell safari / firefox to keep their HTML behind the flash at all costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a link as an example for us?

Usually, you'll want a combo of:

```
wmode:'transparent'
```

and:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="flash">Flash</div>
    <div class="html">HTML</div>
</div>
```

+:

```
.flash,
.html {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
}
.html {
    z-index:1;
}
```

Though I'd like to see a link of the HTML escaping over the top of Flash in your situation.

**EDIT:**

Here's an example I put together, using SWFObject, to position Flash on top of HTML and using the above solution to have everything display as you'd expect: http://codefinger.co.nz/public/flash_atop_html/

Tested in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, IE.

Comment: Wasn't quite what I needed but it did get me in the right direction. I upgraded to the latest version of flash and then put the swf in a separate div with absolute positioning and it's own z-index.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you use wmode like below

```
    <object width="296" height="81"><param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<embed src="yourFileName.swf" wmode="transparent" width="296" height="81" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" /></object>
```

Comment: @jckdnk111 is using SWFObject.